# LESSCSS: interpolation of a mixin argument

Tags: less, mixins, string-interpolation

I have the following code:

```
@red_SOPRA: orange;
@red: red;
.gradient(@color) when (@color = red)
{
  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, @color 0%,yellow 100%);
}

div
{
  .gradient(red);
}
```

Compiled into:

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff0000 0%, #ffff00 100%);
}
```

I would like to add "*_SOPRA*" to the end of variable "`@color`" present in background definition, in order to obtain an interpolated and dynamic name of variable used in mixin.

I tried with `@@` and `@{color}` definitions but without success.

How to obtain a generated background like this (with value "#ffa500" - @red_SOPRA value - instead of "#ff0000")?

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffa500 0%, #ffff00 100%);
}
```

Comment: wont this do: .gradient(@red_SOPRA); ?

Comment: Because I'll have also "@blu_SOPRA".... I need to have a "dynamic" name.... practically, color value used in gradient definition should be a "merging" between string passed through @color variable and "_SOPRA" one

Comment: In current Less versions the standard colour keywords (e.g. `red`) are *immediately* converted to their hex representation (e.g. `#ff0000`) so `"@{color}"` would actually be expanded into "#ff0000" (so instead of `red_SOPRA` you get `#ff0000_SOPRA`). To prevent this you have to use `red` with quotes (e.g. `"red"` or `~"red"` depending on where you use it).

Answer (score 2):

### Option #1

Unless I'm missing something from what you are trying to achieve, then simply removing the guard expression `when (@color = red)` will get a "dynamic" value output for `@color`, allowing it to be called directly by `@red_SOPRA` or `@blu_SOPRA` (whatever you pass).

**LESS**

```
@red_SOPRA: orange;
@red: red;
.gradient(@color) 
{
  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, @color 0%, yellow 100%);
}

div {
  .gradient(@red_SOPRA);
}
```

**CSS Output**

As you wanted...

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffa500 0%, #ffff00 100%);
}
```

### Option 2

You can set up the mixin to perform a "'merging' between string passed" and the "_SOPRA" suffix, something like this:

**LESS**

```
@red_SOPRA: orange;
@blu_SOPRA: blue;
.gradient(@pre; @SOPRA: ~'@{pre}_SOPRA'; @color: @@SOPRA) 
{
  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, @color 0%,yellow 100%);
}

div
{
  .gradient('red');
}

.test {
  .gradient('blu');
}
```

**CSS Output**

```
div {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ffa500 0%, #ffff00 100%);
}
.test {
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #0000ff 0%, #ffff00 100%);
}
```

This will not fail gracefully if `@color` does not resolve to a valid `@@SOPRA` value.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I would like to thank ScottS for his answer, especially second option that is what I needed.

Secondly, I add solution that finally yesterday I found by myself, very similar in philosophy but little different and (maybe) easier to understand by newby, due to a temp variable.

```
@red_SOPRA: orange;
@red: red;

.gradient(@color) when (@color = 'red')
{
  @stop-1:~"@{color}_SOPRA";

  background: linear-gradient( 180deg, @@stop-1 0%,yellow 100%);
}

div
{
  .gradient('red');
}
```

Philosophy is the same, but with this "double passage" I think that could be more "talking"... :-)

UPDATE:
After correct comment of  **seven-phases-max**, I updaded my solution. Please note that parameter must be passed as string with `'red'`

Comment: The only problem is that it's not working: `SyntaxError: variable @#ff0000_SOPRA is undefined in ...` (you need to use `'red'` instead of  `red` :). Btw., `@stop-1: ~"@{color}_SOPRA";` can be just `@stop-1: "@{color}_SOPRA";` (i.e. no need for `~` there).